# How to get history of scheduled task in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to get history of specific task from task scheduler using c#.
Could any one help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. The API reference is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383608(v=vs.85).aspx but it doesn't mention history as far as I can see. Also the examples are all in scripting languages or C++, so I don't think you can access the API directly using C#.

Comment: Even [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) doesn't have any structure to read history part. I don't think there is a way to do it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason Task Scheduler API doesn't allow access to task history is that it's kept in Event Log. When you check the task history in Task Scheduler you can see it's log name is Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational. Same logs can be accessed in Event Viewer (Applications and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> TaskScheduler -> Operational)

I tried to get those entries using EventLog class but apparently we can't. I found this post suggesting a different approach: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/882df3d5-9a9b-437b-a6ab-e09873ce6ece/cant-access-event-log-for-tasks?forum=csharplanguage

I fiddled with the code just to see if it would work in this case and looks like it does:

```
EventLogReader log2 = new EventLogReader("Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational");

for (EventRecord eventInstance = log2.ReadEvent(); null != eventInstance; eventInstance = log2.ReadEvent())
{
    if (!eventInstance.Properties.Select(p => p.Value).Contains("\\{YOUR SCHEDULED TASK NAME}}"))
    {
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Event ID: {0}", eventInstance.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Publisher: {0}", eventInstance.ProviderName);

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", eventInstance.FormatDescription());
    }
    catch (EventLogException)
    {
    }

    EventLogRecord logRecord = (EventLogRecord)eventInstance;
    Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", logRecord.FormatDescription());
}
```

\{YOUR SCHEDULED TASK NAME}} can be found in details section of logs under EventData. This way I could out history for a specific task.

I don't think you can run LINQ queries and get entries between dates or only get the failed ones etc but it might be a starting point.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have been programming C# for I don't know how many years and I have never thought of using a `for` loop like that for reading in data. That pattern is perfect for reading in any kind of "streamed" data where the last record has a special value. I might start using that for `Stream.Read(` loops.

Answer (score 2):

Download `Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.dll` from following link;

> http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/releases/view/120747

And add it as a reference in your C# program. 
Below is code to get history for particular scheduled task;

```
    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
    {

        TaskEventLog log = new TaskEventLog("taskPath");
        List<ListViewItem> c = new List<ListViewItem>(100);

        foreach (TaskEvent item in log)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Level);
            Console.WriteLine(item.TimeCreated);
            Console.WriteLine(item.EventId);
            Console.WriteLine(item.TaskCategory);
            Console.WriteLine(item.OpCode);
            Console.WriteLine(item.ActivityId);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation to Volkan Paksoy's answer this will allow you to query remote computers on your network. I've also added `usings` for the disposable objects

```
void Main()
{
    using (var session = new EventLogSession("remote server name"))
    {
        GetCompletedScheduledTaskEventRecords(session, "Your scheduled tasks name")
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeCreated)
            .Select(r => new { CompletedTime = r.TimeCreated, r.TaskDisplayName, Props = string.Join(" | ", r.Properties.Select(p => p.Value)) })
            .Dump("Said Tasks Completed"); //using linqpad's Dump method, this just outputs the results to the display
    }
}
//If you don't want completed tasks remove the second part in the where clause
private List<EventRecord> GetCompletedScheduledTaskEventRecords(EventLogSession session, string scheduledTask)
{
    const int TASK_COMPLETED_ID = 102;
    var logquery = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational", PathType.LogName, "*[System/Level=4]") { Session = session };
    return GetRecords(logquery, 
        x=> x.Properties.Select(p => p.Value).Contains($@"\{scheduledTask}") && x.Id == TASK_COMPLETED_ID).ToList();
}
private IEnumerable<EventRecord> GetRecords(EventLogQuery query, Func<EventRecord, bool> filter)
{
    using (var reader = new EventLogReader(query))
    {
        for (var record = reader.ReadEvent(); null != record; record = reader.ReadEvent())
        {
            if (!filter(record)) continue;

            yield return record;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EventLogReader log2 = new EventLogReader("Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational");
            for (EventRecord eventInstance = log2.ReadEvent();
                null != eventInstance; eventInstance = log2.ReadEvent())
            {
                int result = DateTime.Compare(eventInstance.TimeCreated.GetValueOrDefault(), DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2));
               // do the specific task

            }
```