# How can you determine which Windows Task Scheduler iteration you are on if you have used the Repeat option?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

For purposes of discussion, let's say I have created a Task in the Windows Task Scheduler and have set it to Repeat every 5 minutes for 1 hour. Other than scrolling through the History and counting, is there a way to answers questions like how many iterations have occurred, which iteration is next, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately, I neglected to mention that I am using Excel VBA so my task is calling a macro enabled Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

The data for this is kept in the Event log and you can read it through code.

There are a couple of approaches outlined in this question that you may find helpful as well :

[How to get history of scheduled task in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557987/how-to-get-history-of-scheduled-task-in-c)

Comment: very interesting